# How to format PHP date to represent month with the first 3 letters?

Tags: php, date-formatting

I have a PHP code that will display the date format which is

`{{date('F d, Y', strtotime($po->due_date))}}`

and it will output something like "September 02, 2016", how can I format this date into "Sep 02, 2016"?

Comment: Did you try and google it? Perhaps googling the function you are using? I know for a fact that you would find the answer in php's own docs.

Comment: Search http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for "A short textual representation of a month, three letters"

Answer (score 0):

It's `M d, Y`. I would recommend you to add `due_date` to `$dates` property in your model:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'due_date',
];
```

Then you can display it `$po->due_date->format('M d, Y')` instead of `date('M d, Y', strtotime($po->due_date))`